# Lost my car keys inside my car. I am definitely unable to find them again despite 5 peoples paid me for a 700 Km ride tomorrow evening

Tags: car, keys

Everything is in the title.
the inside of my Toyota Yaris is black and here’s how the key looks like :
[image: car key]

I think they put the keys in the boot, but there is a 130Kg (250lbs) engine I can’t lift alone (and my left feet is broken but the transmission is automatic).

I absolutely need a way to start the engine tomorrow, not only for myself but for the 5 peoples who paid me and have no longer the possibility to book public transport alternatives (which includes me as I need to pass my student exams next monday).
The car is currently in the street in front of my home in France and **doors are left unlocked** as result.

I also got my driver license less than 6 months ago so no car rental agency will accept to lend me a non stick shift car.

## Update :

I found the keys : they fell under the engine. Looks like I will need quick bodybuilding as I don’t have a jack.

Comment: A repair shop working on sundays is something you don’t usually hear of in France.

Comment: 5 people and a 130kg engine in the trunk of a Yaris? mmm

Comment: @ON5MFJurgen : peoples on https://blablacar.fr aren’t forced to pick up my ride (or rather they are forced since they have no alternative to arrive in time).

Comment: Where’s the spare key? Cars normally come with 2 sets of keys. Post a picture of the key under the engine. Normally the engine would be under the bonnet (front of the car), not the boot (back of the car). The front of the car sometimes (usually?) has an open floor that you could sweep the key towards. Even if you’re keeping an extra engine in the boot, you can try fishing the key out with a magnet.

Comment: @Lawrence previous owner lost it when I bought the car, had left the car for 2 months with keys at the repair shop and got it back only before‑yesterday so I hadn’t the time to make a new one. An alternative for lifting the engine would be to [sell it today](https://www.ebay.com/itm/223339492881).

Comment: Ah, so it *is* a spare engine in the boot! Is the back seat collapsible? Pushing down the rear seats gives you more angles to try.

Comment: @Lawrence Collapsing the back seat would make a great answer!

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comments, you actually have a second engine tucked away in the boot/trunk of your car, and your keys are underneath that engine, out of reach.

The rear sets of a Yaris [fold down](https://gogetms.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000255770-Rear-seats). Folding down your rear seats gives you access to some parts of the engine that are hard to reach from behind the car.

If the engine is leaning against the backs of the rear seats, take care that the engine doesn’t topple when the seats are lowered. Close the hatch (rear door) before folding down the rear seats.

Answer (score 2):

Ask your neighbors to help shift the engine. Or use a crowbar or other lever to move the engine. Or put a wedge under the engine near the keys, use a hammer to push the wedge under the engine (you only need to move the engine a few mm to free the keys, probably).

If the keys are out of reach, get a piece of metal wire (electrical installation wire, Coat hanger, etc.), bend it into a hook and use that to fish for the keys.